# For symmetric monoidal categories, the monoidal product is a monoidal functor

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Has anyone got a reference for the following fact?

> If $\mathcal X$ is a symmetric monoidal category, then $\_\otimes\_\colon\mathcal X\times\mathcal X \to \mathcal X$ is a strong monoidal functor. Moreover, the associators and unitors in $\mathcal X$ are monoidal natural transformations.

The key point here is the existence of a natural transformation
$$
(a \otimes b) \otimes (c \otimes d) \to (a \otimes c) \otimes (b \otimes d)\,,
$$
which is why we need symmetry.

Comment: You could also get this transformation with a *braided* monoidal category (but I don't know if this would make $\otimes $ strong monoidal).

Comment: @ArnaudD. My guess is that this is still true for braided monoidal categories, though it's harder to show since we can't immediately apply the coherence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

See Proposition 2 (page 13) of Joyal–Street's [Braided monoidal categories](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/%7Estreet/JS1.pdf). (Perhaps also relevant is Roberts's [A braided monoidal category is symmetric if and only if the product is braided](https://github.com/DavidMichaelRoberts/Sandbox/blob/master/symmetric_mult_braided.pdf).)